# SUM values from same row where multiple columns equal same value

Tags: php, sql, count, sum

I am trying to get an output of the amount of animal types for each "booking" record in my database, the database structure is similar to this.

```
bid, name, business, animal_type1, animal_size1, animal_type2, animal_size2, animal_type3, animal_size3, animal_type4, animal_size4
```

An example record would be

```
1, John Smith, John Smith's Pets, Dog, Small, Dog, Medium, Cat, Small, Dog, Giant, Dog, Large
```

I am trying to get an output like this.

```
2x Small Dogs
1x Medium Dogs
1x Small Cat
1x Giant Dog
```

This is the code I have been playing with based on tutorials but not having much luck, and this method would require running a separate query for each type and size.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT animal_type1,animal_type2,animal_type3,animal_type4,animal_type5 AS total
        FROM bookings WHERE bid = '$bid' AND `animal_type1 = 'Dog' AND booking_status = 'Unbooked'";
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["mysqli_ston"], $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result); ?>
<?php echo $rows['COUNT(animal_type1) + COUNT(animal_type2) + COUNT(animal_type3) + COUNT(animal_type4) + COUNT(animal_type5)'] ?>

<?php echo $rows['total']; ?>
```

Any suggestions or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify what SQL Engine you're using?

Comment: SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*),'x') AS N,CONCAT('animal_type1',' ' 'animal_size1') AS M FROM BOOKINGS WHERE bid = '$bid' GROUP BY CONCAT('animal_type1',' ' 'animal_size1')...  use a loop to change size & type suffix like CONCAT('animal_type$i',' ' 'animal_size$i').. echo the result as per your count

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you're code is alot more advanced than my current level, I'll play around with it and see how I go, thanks again for the response.

Comment: see the answer & execute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
{
$str_1='animal_type'.$i;
$str_2='animal_size'.$i;
$qry="SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*),'x') AS N,CONCAT($str_1,' ',$str_2) AS M FROM BOOKINGS WHERE bid = '$bid' GROUP BY CONCAT($str_1,' ',$str_2)";
$res=mysqli_query($qry);
while($result=mysqli_fetch_object($res))
{
echo $result->N.' '.$result->M;
}
}
```

check this..

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this code and it's just displaying white space, so I added echo before $qry and got this, is this correct?

SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*),'x') AS N,CONCAT(,' ',animal_size1) AS M FROM BOOKINGS WHERE bid = '1' GROUP BY CONCAT(,' ',animal_size1)

Comment: It is echoing this "SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(*),'x') AS N,CONCAT(animal_type1,' ',animal_size1) AS M FROM BOOKINGS WHERE bid = '1' GROUP BY CONCAT(animal_type1,' ',animal_size1)" but still white space, not sure what I am doing wrong.

wait I haven't added the db connection, I'll try that.

Comment: run this on your back end editor e.g php myadmin..you will get the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76988/discussion-between-jcain-and-devlakshman).